# Installing Ubuntu from disk image from PC with all the right settings once

Tags: software-installation, disk

Okay, I'm pretty new to Ubuntu but bear with me, even if this question sounds clueless.

For a local school, I have advised them to switch to Ubuntu, to save budget and yes, to break the Microsoft monopoly on the school kids IT-education. Obviously, now I'm the one who can handle all those installations. And it's turning out to be more of a hassle than I expected, since they do use network-printers and all kinds of local settings I can't install from home.

Long story short, what would be ideal for me is to set up a PC with all the right settings once, copy that installation and just install it exactly like that on all the other PC's as well. It would allow me to just install one PC after the other, correct printers installed and everything. Can that be done? Do I use a USB-stick? Or am I better off installing one PC as a server to handle this? Any advise is welcomed, the local school kids count on us to teach them something else than Windows and Office!

Answer (score 0):

If all computers are similar.

I suggest to you, that once set one of them, clone your hard disk and copy it to each of the other computers.

It is highly recommended that you do with root enabled, and then in each of the cloned computers, high users without administrator permissions.

To clone can be used in simultaneous Clonezilla.

http://clonezilla.org/

Clonezilla server edition is for massive deployment, it can clone many computers simultaneously.